# Find max word in an array (MIPS Assembly)

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I am trying to find the max word in an array using assembly. I have written the following but seems my loop is always branching. Any help is appreciated!

**Solution is in the comments, thank you Jester**

```
# find max from array
#
.data
array:  .word   3, 4, 7, 6, 5
max:    .word   0
.text
#
# -- register assignments  --
# $2 = counter
# $3 = sum
# $6 = loop limit (20)
#
# counter = 0
    and $2, $0, $0
# sum = 0
    and $3, $0, $0
    addi    $6, $0, 20
loop:
# if array[i] < max save array[i] as max
    lw  $4, array($2)
    ble     $3, $4, incrementCount
    move    $3, $4
incrementCount:
# counter++
# (words are 4 bytes, so advance counter by 4)
    addi    $2, $2, 4
# if counter < 5, loop (really < 20)
    blt $2, $6, loop
done:   sw  $3, max
```

Comment: `sw  $3, ($4)` should probably be `move $3, $4` as $4 is not an address.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I have made the adjustment. It still seems my program is not branching

Comment: Also your branch is reversed, you are skipping if the max is less than the current. How about you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: brilliant. changed this: `ble $3, $4, incrementCount` to `ble $4, $3, incrementCount`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The operand order for your `ble` is incorrect. You're initially setting `$3 = 0`, and then you do `ble $3, $4, incrementCount`, i.e. `if (0 <= element_just_loaded) goto incrementCount`. This condition will always be true, since all the elements in your array are greater than 0, and the value of `$3` will keep being 0 since the only time you change it is if the branch isn't taken.

The solution would be to switch the operands around so that you do `ble $4, $3, incrementCount`, i.e. `if (element_just_loaded <= current_max) goto incrementCount`.